# How can I sort fonts by category with the Google Webfonts API?

Tags: google-webfonts

I'd like to be able to identify all of the fonts in a particular category (sans, sans-serif), which is possible from Google's web font viewer, but doesn't seem to work via the API.

https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/developer_api#Details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: get it from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/4086108)

**Longer answer**: Here is a tiny scala program to do this. You'll need to checkout googlefontdirectory project from http://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory to use this and change the `basePath` in the program below:

```
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.io.FileInputStream
import collection.mutable
import collection.JavaConverters._

object Webfonts {
  private val basePath = new java.io.File("/path/to/googlefontdirectory")

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val fontDetailsList = mutable.ListBuffer.empty[FontDetails]
    val categoryMap = mutable.Map.empty[String, java.util.List[String]]

    val gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
    for (font <- FontsList.fonts ) {
      fontDetailsList += gson.fromJson(IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(new java.io.File(basePath, font))), classOf[FontDetails])
    }

    fontDetailsList.filter(_.subsets.contains("latin")).foreach((font) => {
      val a = categoryMap.getOrElseUpdate(font.category, new java.util.ArrayList[String]())
      a.add(font.name)
    })

    val json = gson.toJson(categoryMap.asJava)
    println(json)
  }


  case class FontDetails(name: String, license: String, category: String, size: Int, subsets: Array[String]) {
    override def toString = category + " : " + name
  }

}

object FontsList {
  val fonts = Array(
    "./apache/aclonica/METADATA.json",
    "./apache/calligraffitti/METADATA.json",
    "./apache/cherrycreamsoda/METADATA.json",
    "./ufl/ubuntucondensed/METADATA.json",
    "./ufl/ubuntumono/METADATA.json"

  )
}
```

You can get the complete FontsList at https://gist.github.com/4085914

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, the gist+json is incredibly helpful.

Comment: This gist file is now ten months old, and so will be out-of-date. Also be aware that the fonts and metadata in the Google hg repository will be ahead of the released fonts on the Google API. You will need to filter the font families by those supplied in the API, but even then the categories and subsets will not always be correct (the API will be behind the hg repo). I found this when extracting the metadata myself (https://github.com/academe/GoogleFontMetadata) - there are subsets in there that are not released at the time of writing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the API support this. If you check the JSON file returned from the API, it does not show this information. A similar question was asked at the Google Web Font group, but no answers.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/googlefontdirectory-discuss/U2cROKUjRqM